# TFS Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013.4 original templates

Tags: tfs

A previous developer has edited our on premise TFS 2017.3 server process templates (I think) as I cannot create a new project as I get the following

> [Error] The following element contains an error: RequirementBacklog/States. TF400587: This element defines the states for work items that appear on your backlog. Each state must exist in at least one of the work item types belong to category defined in: 'RequirementBacklog/States'. The following state does not exist in any of the work item types: Testing.
>
> [08:59:37.530]   The following element contains an error: TaskBacklog/States. TF400587: This element defines the states for work items that appear on your backlog. Each state must exist in at least one of the work item types belong to category defined in: 'TaskBacklog/States'. The following state does not exist in any of the work item types: Testing.
>
> [08:59:37.530]   The following element contains an error: BugWorkItems/BugWorkItems. TF400506: This element defines the states for work items that represent Bugs or Defects. Each state must exist in at least one of the work item types that are defined in: BugWorkItems. The following states do not exist in any of the work item types: Testing.
>
> [08:59:37.530]   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.WorkItemTracking.Common.InvalidProjectSettingsException: The following element contains an error:
>   RequirementBacklog/States. TF400587: This element defines the states for work items that appear on your backlog. Each state must exist in at least one of the work item types belong to category defined in: 'RequirementBacklog/States'. The following state does not exist in any of the work item types: Testing.
>
> [08:59:37.530]   The following element contains an error: TaskBacklog/States. TF400587:

I have done a fair bit of googling and understand that somewhere a process template has been edited and Testing state added/modified. Obviously the solution is to fix the template in question. But I don't know which one was changed and we have many projects within TFS.

I cannot find the original templates which came with TFS so as to restore them over the potentially changed one.

The one complication is - during the creation is it using the "TFS Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013.4" template which I choose. If so, is it specifically this one which has been broken? And so how do I restore the original.

Comment: If you can't create a new project, it's the **template itself** that has the problem, not any specific project. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/manage-process-templates?view=azure-devops-2019

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the focus - althaough I still wonder if I cannot resolve the issue with the template - can I download the original somewhere ?

Comment: @MadEddie when you create a new team project you can choose the template, the default templates are Agile/Scrum/CMMI, are they available? can you choose one of them?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Yes they are - and they work, but the Scrum 2013.4 does not work - as shown with the error in my original post. I just need to be able to "reset" this template.

Comment: @MadEddie You can't reset the template, the "clean" template is Scrum, your company edited the Scrum and create a new template (Scrum 2013.4), in the new template have an errors. you can fix the errors (one by one) or choose another template that working.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk - The Scrum template does not work - I suppose this has been edited and broken too. How can I get the original version which shipped with TFS ?

Comment: @MadEddie Did you get the same error?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Sorry - it errored on screen but actually successfully created the project :) thanks for your help

Comment: @MadEddie Great! Your'e welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to create a team project with a custom process template that is broken and should be fixed manually (read the errors one by one and fix the XML files), you **can't** "reset" it.

You can create a new team project with the default process templates (Agile/Scrum/CMMI) that come with TFS (they should be "clean" templates).

The original of your custom template probably is "Scrum".